# E2316 'any_of' is not a member of 'std'

Tags: c++, std, c++builder, stl-algorithm, c++builder-6

So I'm trying to use `std::any_of()` function, but C++ Builder 6 says that there is an error:

> [C++ Error] Unit1.cpp(93): E2316 'any_of' is not a member of 'std'

But I have `#include <algorithm>` in my Unit1.h

```
#ifndef Unit1H
#define Unit1H
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#include <Classes.hpp>
#include <Controls.hpp>
#include <StdCtrls.hpp>
#include <Forms.hpp>
#include <ExtCtrls.hpp>
#include <set>
#include <algorithm>    // std::set_union, std::sort, etc
#include <vector>       // std::vector
#include <math.h>
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

My Unit1.cpp:

```
void __fastcall TForm1::Button7Click(TObject *Sender)
{
        int el = StrToInt(LabeledEdit1->Text);
        if ( std::any_of(A.begin(), A.end(), (*MyIteratorA==el)) ){
                ShowMessage("true");
        }else{
                ShowMessage("false");
        }

}
```

It's weird, because I'm using such functions as `std::set_union()`, `std::set_intersection()`, `std::set_difference()` in the same programm and everything worked fine untill `std::any_of`.

Sorry for bad english.

Comment: any_of is C++11 (and newer) did you compile with C++11 enabled? (something like -std=c++11 or similar)

Comment: Side note: '__fastcall' looks ancient

Comment: @DieterLücking: Borland's `__fastcall` calling convention is for compatibility with Delphi's `register` calling convention, which is certainly not "ancient".  Maybe you are thinking of Microsoft's `__fastcall` (which is `__msfastcall` in Borland).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C++ Builder 32-bit is not C++11 compliant. For all of the c++11 features you need to use the 64-bit version.

`std::set_union`, `std::set_intersection`, and `std::set_difference` are not c++11 features, which is why they work.

Comment: C++Builder 6 does not support 64-bit development (and thus does not support C++11).  That was added in C++Builder XE3.